# Segmentation Fault when I try to add a new WaitingRoom in my linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

When I run the code below with only one `WaitingRoom` created it works perfectly fine but if I add another one then it gives me segfault.

My code creates a `WaitingRoom` as the HEAD of a list and then it adds students in alphabetical order. This works just fine, but when I try to add another `WaitingRoom` it gives me segfault at the `insertinRoom` function at the first if clause.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct studenti {
    char name[100];
    struct studenti* next;
} studenti;

typedef struct WaitingRoom {
    int ID;
    char parola[100];
    struct WaitingRoom* next;
    struct studenti* next_S;
} WaitingRoom;

studenti* CreateStudent(char* name)
{
    studenti* S = (studenti*)malloc(sizeof(studenti));
    strcpy(S->name, name);
    S->next = NULL;

    return S;
}

WaitingRoom* createWaitingRoom(int ID, char* parola){
    WaitingRoom* WR = (WaitingRoom*)malloc(sizeof(WaitingRoom));
    strcpy(WR->parola, parola);
    WR->ID = ID;
    WR->next = NULL;

    return WR;
}

void insertinRoom(WaitingRoom* WR, char* name){
    studenti* S;
    S = CreateStudent(name);

    if (WR->next_S == NULL || strcmp(WR->next_S->name, name) > 0) {
        S->next=WR->next_S;
        WR->next_S = S;
    }
    else {
        studenti* current  = WR->next_S;
        while(current->next != NULL && strcmp(current->next->name, name) > 0)
        {
            current=current->next;
        }
        S->next = current->next;
        current->next = S;
    }
}

void printWaitingRoom(WaitingRoom* WR) {
    studenti* current = WR->next_S;
    printf("Waiting Romom este %d cu parola %s\n", WR->ID, WR->parola);
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", current->name);
        current = current->next;
    }

}

void printall(WaitingRoom* WR){
    WaitingRoom* current = WR;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printWaitingRoom(current);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    WaitingRoom* WR1 = createWaitingRoom(6969, "Muiedinamo");
    insertinRoom(WR1, "BOOm1");
    insertinRoom(WR1, "AOOm2");
    insertinRoom(WR1, "DOOm3");
    insertinRoom(WR1, "COOm4");

/*
    WaitingRoom* WR2 = createWaitingRoom(1234, "AStae ");
    insertinRoom(WR2, "B1");
    insertinRoom(WR2, "AO2");
    insertinRoom(WR2, "D3");
    insertinRoom(WR2, "C4");

    WR1->next = WR2;
    */
    printWaitingRoom(WR1);
    //printall(WR1);

    return 0;
}
```

I intended to create `WaitingRoom`'s, connect them and then print them 1 by 1 and the whole list with `PrintAll` function.

Comment: You don't initialize `next_S` in `createWaitingRoom`.

Comment: You should learn how to use your debugger. Even with very basic knowledge of your debugger you would have found this bug in less than ten minutes.